# JIRA v6.2 - get project start date via REST API 2

Tags: json, rest, jira

I need to get a "project start date" via REST in Jira 6.2, I trying to make request in  URLJira/rest/api/2/project/ProjectName and the response is a Json but i can't see the startDate (or something like that), unfortunately i can't connect directly to the database.
I made a wrong request or is there a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by project "start date" ? Do you need the date that the project was created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the start date equal to the date of creation of the first issue

Answer (score 1):

Standard JIRA projects do not have start dates in themselves (unless you are using the third-party Profields plugin, in which case you should check out the [Profields API documentation](http://profields.rest.deiser.com)).

However, *versions* within a standard JIRA project do have start dates. To get the project version list, including start dates, make a REST request to:

YOURJIRAURL/rest/api/2/project/YOURPROJ/versions

This returns something like this, including the `userStartDate` property:

```
[{
id:"11590",
name:"1.0",
archived:false,
released:false,
startDate:"2013-01-01",
userStartDate:"1/Jan/13",
projectId:10130
}]
```